# Operations and fungibility of units

Tags: arithmetic

From the commutative property of the reals, we have that:
$$
x+y=y+x
$$
In other words, the order of items does not matter, just their overall
quantity when determining the sum. Imagine I have \$5. Here,
$
1+1+1+1+1=5
$.
I can re-arrange the $1's$ in many different ways, $P_{5}^{5}$
to be exact, which yield 5 as a sum. In that sense, the dollars are
fully fungible, and there is no well defined ``sequence''.

On the
other hand, say someone asked me my age. I was born in 1990.
As such,
I am 30 years old at this point. But, there is a well defined sequence
from 1990. My first year was 1990, second 1991, third 1992 and so
on. Yes, I could perform the addition in whichever way possible, (add
2010 to 1991 to 1992 etc), but each number has a meaning, which is
not as interchangeable as the previous case. In that sense, order
has a meaning. However, arithmetic operations are still defined in
the same case as above. In other words, why are arithmetic operations
independent of whether or not the underlying quantities are interchangeable?
Is there any class of operations that does indeed change in this setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to **add** years together? Like 1990 + 1991 ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean. Do you mean to say that $1990 + 1991 \neq 1991 + 1990$ ? (Because you said: "Order has a meaning")

Comment: I mean that when it comes to age, there is a well defined sequence. If I say I am 30, I reach this number by considering 2020-1990. Here, each underlying unit of time is a specific year, (1990, 1991 etc). I can get to my age by any other order (1 year in 2010, 1 year in 1998 etc, as long as I don't repeat years, and exhaust all 30). But, here, 1 year in 1990 is different from 1 year in 1991 (in that they are not fungible).

Comment: @MattiP. is it still super confusing?